# Validate two inputs as one

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-4

I have two separate inputs: `date` and `time`. I'd like to validate both of these inputs with the `after` rule. How would I do this? Here are the rules so far:

```
$now = (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i');

$rules = [
    'date' => [
        'required',
        'date',
        "after:$now",
    ],
    'time' => [
        'required',
        'regex:/^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/',
    ],
];
```

Currently, validation is ignoring time and the date will pass when the time is set to something invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
class MyRequest extends Request 
{
    public function rules() 
    {
        $this->normalize();

        return ['date_time' => 'required|date|after:now'];
    }

    public function normalize()
    {
        $this->merge([
            'date_time' => $this->input('date') . ' ' . $this->input('time')
        ]);
    }
}
```

The main thing here is to call normalize to build and add a new `date_time` key value to the request and then validate with whatever rules you prefer.